# Fields initialized from async functions in JS object literals: will they break concurrency?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Is there a way, in a JavaScript object literal, to initialize some fields with the result of async functions while ensuring they will still run concurently?

Here is what I tried:

```
async function f() { /* ... */; return 0; }
async function g() { /* ... */; return 1; }

async function init() {
  const o = { f: f(), g: g() };
  return o;
}

init().then(console.log)
//> { f: Promise { ... }, f: Promise { ... } }
// XXX not what I want: I want *values* not promises
```

If I write the code above, `f()` and `g()` are resolved in parallel, but `obj.f` and `obj.g` will hold the promise returned by the function, not the resolved value.

On the other hand, with the syntax below I obtain an object whose fields contains values, but it seems to me the `f()` and `g()` calls were resolved sequentially. Or am I wrong here?

```
async function init() {
  const o = { f: await f(), g: await g() };
  return o;
}

init().then(console.log)
//> { f: 0, g: 1 }
// ??? did `f()` and `g()` run concurrently or sequentially here?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you need to use `Promise.all` to wait for multiple concurrent things:

```js
async function getF() { /* ... */; return 0; }
async function getG() { /* ... */; return 1; }

async function init() {
  const [f, g] = await Promise.all([getF(), getG()]);
  return {f, g};
}

init().then(console.log);
```

Comment: Why won't the two `await` calls in the `init()` function work like any sequence of `await` calls would work in an `async` function? (The second version of the OP code.)

Comment: @Pointy They do work, but as you say they are *sequential*. OP wanted to ensure that the functions run concurrently.

Comment: oh ~ light bulb ~ because the second one won't start until the first resolves, got it.